# Vue.js with GraphQl pagination

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm using Graphql for the first time with vue.js but cannot get pagination
working.

The vue component looks like this:

```
    <template>
        <ApolloQuery :query="require('./breeds.gql')" :variables="{ page }" v-slot="{ result: { loading, error, data }, query }">
            <div v-if="data">
                <div class="flex flex-wrap lg:-m-2" v-if="data.breeds">
                    <breed class="gutter-three-items h-64" :breed="breed" :key="breed.id" v-for="breed in data.breeds"></breed>
                </div>

                <div v-if="data.breeds && !isLoading">
                    <h3 class="text-primary p-2 md:p-0">
                        Geen resultaat
                    </h3>
                </div>

                <div class="flex justify-start w-full">
                    <load-more container="scroll-breeds" :loading="isLoading" @load="page++"> </load-more>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ApolloQuery>
    </template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            page: 1,
        };
    }
</script>
```

The breeds.gql looks like this:

```
query Breeds($page: Int!) {
    breeds(page: $page) {
        id
        name_nl
        slug_nl
        full_overview_image
        total_posts
        is_activated
        total_dogs
    }
  }
```

However when I look into my network tab the response is this:

> Cannot query field "id" on type "BreedPaginator

What could I be doing wrong here?

For my backend I use this https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse.

The schema looks like this:

```
"A datetime string with format `Y-m-d H:i:s`, e.g. `2018-01-01 13:00:00`."
scalar DateTime @scalar(class: "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Types\\Scalars\\DateTime")

"A date string with format `Y-m-d`, e.g. `2011-05-23`."
scalar Date @scalar(class: "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Types\\Scalars\\Date")

type Breed {
    id: ID,
    name_nl: String
    slug_nl: String
    full_overview_image: String
    total_posts: String
    is_activated: Boolean
    total_dogs: String
}

type Query {
    breeds: [Breed] @paginate
}
```

Please help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `@paginate` directive, you transform the type of your field to a Paginator type specific to the original field's type. This is explained in [the docs](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#paginate):

> This directive is meant to be used on root query fields:
>
> ```
> type Query {
>    posts: [Post!]! @paginate
> }
> ```
>
> The schema definition is automatically transformed to this:
>
> ```
> type Query {
>    posts(first: Int!, page: Int): PostPaginator
> }
>
> "A paginated list of Post items."
> type PostPaginator {
>    "A list of Post items."
>    data: [Post!]!
>
>    "Pagination information about the list of items."
>    paginatorInfo: PaginatorInfo!
> }
> ```
>
> And can be queried like this:
>
> ```
> {
>    posts(first: 10) {
>        data {
>            id
>            title
>        }
>        paginatorInfo {
>            currentPage
>            lastPage
>        }
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks I already saw that in the doc's but I still have no Idea why my code is not working.

Comment: Because you are not querying your schema correctly. By applying the directive, `breeds` will now only have two fields -- `data` and `paginatorInfo`. The fields you're trying to query (`id`, etc.) will now be under `data`, as shown in the example above.

Comment: You should write your queries inside GraphQL Playground, GraphiQL, Altair or some similar tool before using them in your front end code.